# Slicing DNA sequence using chunks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a Python Program in which a DNA sequence is given in a text file. It has more than 9000 characters. I have to cut the sequence in 3 characters 
so our frame reads from `1 to 3`, then `4 to 6,` then `7 to 9`, which is called as codons.

For Example the sequence is

`ACCTGCCTCTTACGAGGCGACACTCCACCATGGATCACTCCCCTGTGAGGAACTACTGTCTTCACGCAGA`

then I have to cut it in 3 characters. Which I have already done it. My question is how can I take out the GENE sequence from the given DNA? GENE sequence starts from `ATG` and end it on `TAG` or `TAA` or `TGA`.

It is easy to do if I use `Regular Expression`. But the problem is if you look at the above sequence the `ATG` is coming from 30th position to 32nd. While our frame reads from `1 to 3` then `4 to 6`. In this case when it reaches to `28th to 30th`, it doesn't make `ATG`.

Can anyone understand my problem and please help me? I'm sharing my code now:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
from pathlib import Path
dna = Path('C:/Users/abdul/Downloads/Compressed/MAJU/HCV-PK1-sequence - 
edited.txt').read_text()
l = [c for c in dna if c!='\n']
r = len(l)
for x in range(0,r,3):
    y=x+3
    codon = l[x:y]
    a = ''.join(codon)
    print(a)
if(a == re.findall('ATG(...)+?(TAG|TAA|TGA)', dna)):
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the 3 reading frames like so:

```
dna = ''.join(dna)
for frame in [0,1,2]:
    codons = [dna[x:x+3] for x in range(frame,len(dna)-2,3)]
```

But the correct answer is to install biopython and use its sequence manipulation functions. It will also help you read your sequence from file.

A solution that doesn't use biopython:

```
def find_orf(seq,start):
    for pos in range(start+3,len(seq)-2,3):
        codon = seq[pos:pos+3]
        if codon in ['TAA','TAG','TGA']:
            return seq[start:pos+3]
    return seq[start:] # if we don't find inframe stop codon return whole sequence from start codon to end


# Assuming seq is a string, not a list of characters:
seq = 'ACCTGCCTCTTACGAGGCGACACTCCACCATGGATCACTCCCCTGTGAGGAACTACTGTCAGCCTAATTAATAAGGTAAC'
orfs = []
for frame in [0,1,2]:
    for pos in range(frame,len(seq)-2,3):
        codon = seq[pos:pos+3]
        if codon == 'ATG':
            orf = find_orf(seq,pos)
            orfs.append(orf)

print(orfs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I've already read the file easily without biopython. 2nd I've installed BioPython but I don't get it about the sequence manipulation function. I've googled it but I didn't find anything about it. Could you please help me?? If you can.

Comment: OK. Editing my answer to include a solution that doesn't use biopython. I would still really recommend learning this library if you are writing bioinformatics code using python.

Answer (score 0):

Then just change the frame range in order to read from `1 to 3`, `2 to 4` and so on.

You could do this by using `slicing` *feature* in combination with `range` *function*.

```
dna = "ACCTGCCTCTTACGAGGCGACACTCCACCATGGATCACTCCCCTGTGAGGAACTACTGTCTTCACGCAGA"
sequence_length = 3
lst = [dna[i:i+sequence_length] for i in range(0, len(dna) - sequence_length + 1, 1)]
```

Output

```
=> ['ACC', 'CCT', 'CTG', 'TGC', 'GCC', 'CCT', 'CTC', 'TCT', 'CTT', 'TTA', 'TAC', 'ACG', 'CGA', 'GAG', 'AGG', 'GGC', 'GCG', 'CGA', 'GAC', 'ACA', 'CAC', 'ACT', 'CTC', 'TCC', 'CCA', 'CAC', 'ACC', 'CCA', 'CAT', 'ATG', 'TGG', 'GGA', 'GAT', 'ATC', 'TCA', 'CAC', 'ACT', 'CTC', 'TCC', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CCT', 'CTG', 'TGT', 'GTG', 'TGA', 'GAG', 'AGG', 'GGA', 'GAA', 'AAC', 'ACT', 'CTA', 'TAC', 'ACT', 'CTG', 'TGT', 'GTC', 'TCT', 'CTT', 'TTC', 'TCA', 'CAC', 'ACG', 'CGC', 'GCA', 'CAG', 'AGA']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have to read it using 1 to 3 then 4 to 6. Not 1 to 3 and then 2 to 4. Actually the way you are telling me to take out genes from DNA, I have already done it using Regular Expression. But I have to read 1 to 3 frame then 4 to 6 frame. And if it finds ATG or TAG or TAA or TGA in this frame then it will take it out. Otherwise not.
I have already done it using this regular expression but I wouldn't be able to do it by using FRAMES. 
     for m in (re.findall('(ATG(...)+?(TAG|TAA|TGA))', dna)):
          print('gene {}'.format(m[0]))

Comment: @AbdullahQamer, ok, I'm sorry I misunderstood

Comment: No Problem :)
2nd when I'm using your code it also shows some ''GA\n'' these types of entries because the DNA is not in one line that is why. Hope you understand :)